# Generate table with predefined parameters

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a table with these parameters:

```
        # Setting parameters for table
        initial_year=2020
        last_year=2030

        # Setting column names
       
         ## First two columns' names
        The first two columns must have columns with the names 'Wages' and 'Payment'
        
        ### Columns after the second column
        listName = ['column1','column2','column3','column4']
```

In the end, I need to have the table as the table below

[image]

I tried this line of code, but is not working

```
df=pd.DataFrame(rows=range(initial_year,last_year)).add_prefix('Year')
```

Can anybody help me how to solve this problem and generate table as table above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
initial_year=2020
last_year=2030

cols = ['Wages', 'Payment']
listName = ['column1','column2','column3','column4']

df = (pd.DataFrame({'Year': range(initial_year, last_year+1)})
        .reindex(columns=['Year']+cols+listName, fill_value=1)
     )

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Year  Wages  Payment  column1  column2  column3  column4
0   2020      1        1        1        1        1        1
1   2021      1        1        1        1        1        1
2   2022      1        1        1        1        1        1
3   2023      1        1        1        1        1        1
4   2024      1        1        1        1        1        1
5   2025      1        1        1        1        1        1
6   2026      1        1        1        1        1        1
7   2027      1        1        1        1        1        1
8   2028      1        1        1        1        1        1
9   2029      1        1        1        1        1        1
10  2030      1        1        1        1        1        1
```